# using a button max 3 times before disabling it

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to be able to use this button to search oracle three times at most and after the three attempts to disable the button and use a different search. Below is my code when the button is clicked to search first. If the catch is used three times I want to be able to disable the button.

```
private void btnCancelSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Connect to Database
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
        conn.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

        //Define SQL Query (Select)
        strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Bookings WHERE BookingNo = '" + txtCnlBookingNo.Text + "'";

        cmd.CommandText = strSQL;

        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        dr.Read();

        txtBookingNo.Text = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
        txtBkgSurname.Text = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
        txtBkgForename.Text = dr.GetValue(2).ToString();
        txtBkgContactNo.Text = dr.GetValue(3).ToString();
        txtBkgStreet.Text = dr.GetValue(4).ToString();
        txtBkgTown.Text = dr.GetValue(5).ToString();
        txtBkgCounty.Text = dr.GetValue(6).ToString();
        txtBkgCountry.Text = dr.GetValue(7).ToString();
        txtBkgEmail.Text = dr.GetValue(8).ToString();
        cboBkgNoGuests.Text = dr.GetValue(9).ToString();
        cboBkgPayment.Text = dr.GetValue(10).ToString();
        dtpBkgCheckIn.Text = dr.GetValue(11).ToString();
        dtpBkgCheckOut.Text = dr.GetValue(12).ToString();
    }
    catch
    {
        //Display confirmation message
        MessageBox.Show("Not a valid Booking No");
    }
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Do you want this to be per session, per page post or indefinitely?

Comment: Why do you assume the `catch` block is executed every time the button is clicked? Also, where are you closing the connection you open?

Comment: It seems that you are on Windows Forms. Just use a (at least) class level variable to keep track of attemps failures.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your application. You can keep track of a variable called:

```
int ButtonClickedCount = 0;
```

increment this variable everytime the button is clicked. If the click count is exceeded you notify the user or disable the button.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you trying to achieve:

Declare a variable to keep track of the number of times user have clicked, then apply your logic?

```
int count = 0;


private void btnCancelSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if(count <3){
    count++;

    try
    {
        //Connect to Database
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
        conn.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

        //Define SQL Query (Select)
        strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Bookings WHERE BookingNo = '" + txtCnlBookingNo.Text + "'";

        cmd.CommandText = strSQL;

        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        dr.Read();

        txtBookingNo.Text = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
        txtBkgSurname.Text = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
        txtBkgForename.Text = dr.GetValue(2).ToString();
        txtBkgContactNo.Text = dr.GetValue(3).ToString();
        txtBkgStreet.Text = dr.GetValue(4).ToString();
        txtBkgTown.Text = dr.GetValue(5).ToString();
        txtBkgCounty.Text = dr.GetValue(6).ToString();
        txtBkgCountry.Text = dr.GetValue(7).ToString();
        txtBkgEmail.Text = dr.GetValue(8).ToString();
        cboBkgNoGuests.Text = dr.GetValue(9).ToString();
        cboBkgPayment.Text = dr.GetValue(10).ToString();
        dtpBkgCheckIn.Text = dr.GetValue(11).ToString();
        dtpBkgCheckOut.Text = dr.GetValue(12).ToString();
    }
    catch
    {
        //Display confirmation message
        MessageBox.Show("Not a valid Booking No");
    }
}else
{
    //Implement whatever search you want here
    //And disable your button here
}
}
```